# Spring Kafka ProducerRecord Mock Test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

```
ProducerRecord<Key,Value> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, key,value);

ListenableFuture<SendResult<Key,Value>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
```

Test Case

```
@Mock
ProducerRecord<Key,Value> producerRecord;

@Mock
ListenableFuture<SendResult<Key,Value>> future;

@Mock
private KafkaTemplate<Key,Value> producer;
```

When am mocking send method it will return null future object

```
when(producer.send(producerRecord)).thenReturn(future);
```

**Solution I Found**.

I Pass any(ProducerRecord.class) so i will trigger your method and return you future object

```
@Mock
ListenableFuture<SendResult<Key,Value>> future;

@Mock
private KafkaTemplate<Key,Value> producer;

when(producer.send(any(ProducerRecord.class))).thenReturn(future);
```

Answer (score -1):

Besides mocking the `KafkaTemplate#send` method:

```
when(producer.send(producerRecord)).thenReturn(future);
```

You should instruct your class fixture implementation to initialize the mock objects. It should be a pre-instance step as follows:

```
@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

It is common good practice to move mock configuration (common ones) to the set-up step as well:

```
@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    SendResult<Key,Value> result = Mockito.mock(SendResult.class);
    when(future.get()).thenReturn(result);
    when(producer.send(producerRecord)).thenReturn(future);
}
```